# How to cbind multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

```
mydata <- data.frame(a = 2, b = 3, c = 3)
myvec <- c(2, 9, 1)
```

I would like to column bind `mydata` with `myvec`. I want the final output to look something like this:

```
> mydata
  a b c myvec1 myvec2 myvec3
1 2 3 3      2      9      1
```

However, if I simply use `cbind`, I don't get the desired result:

```
> cbind(mydata, myvec)
  a b c myvec
1 2 3 3     2
2 2 3 3     9
3 2 3 3     1
```

One way is to iterate over the entries in `myvec` with a for loop. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to `list`

```
cbind(mydata, setNames(as.list(myvec), paste0('myvec', seq_along(myvec))))
#    a b c myvec1 myvec2 myvec3
#1 2 3 3      2      9      1
```

---

Or another option is

```
mydata[paste0('myvec', seq_along(myvec))] <- myvec
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the vector :

```
cbind(mydata, t(myvec))
#  a b c 1 2 3
#1 2 3 3 2 9 1
```

You can name the columns with `setNames` or `names<-`